# Generic function as functional interface?

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I have the following function which returns an `List` of the same type as which it is passed.

```
<T> List<T> foo(T bar)
{
    ...
}
```

I want to have this same function, except in the form of a [Java Functional Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). I've tried the following:

```
final <T> Function<T, List<T>> foo;
```

But it does not like the `<T>`. If I omit `<T>` like:

```
final Function<T, List<T>> foo;
```

It claims it cannot find type `T`, exactly the same error as if I were to define the original function as:

```
List<T> foo(T bar) // cannot find type 'T'
{
    ...
}
```

I want to have function `foo` as a first class function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re confusing a *method* with a *class*, which may be implemented as a *lambda*.

If `T` isn’t a type in the context of the code, you can’t type anything.

You can do this:

```
class MyClass<T> implements Function<T, List<T>> {
    public List<T> accept(T t) {
         // some impl
    }
}
```